# Replicatiing post request from website form using postman returns 500 internal server error

Tags: forms, http, post, web-scraping, postman

I'm trying to replicate a post request done normally by a website form via postman but the server returns 500 error.

the form website URL that I'm dealing with is [here](http://77.237.94.52:880/CLAE/Search_Attorney.aspx).

what I have done so far is investigate the network request using chrome or safari dev tools, copy the request as cURL, import the cURL in postman and do the request.

what can be the possible reasons for the failure and what are the alternative ways to achieve the same result?

[image]

[image]

Postman Headers:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @PaulDigz I don't know what error you're asking for exactly but I updated the question

Comment: can you please screenshot the header, i tried to request using postman and it's working fine

Comment: whats the error in body show request body

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you must have used invalid request body. The browser shows parsed json body and you might have copied incomple request body.

To get full body click view source and copy the full content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I copied the request by right-clicking the request name and selecting copy > copy as cURL . how can the request body not be completely copied?